Securing self-hosted WCF service using custom authentication
I've an ASP.NET MVC web app which is meant to be used within the enterprise. This web app has a custom authentication implementation. The controller functions will call self-hosted WCF services running in the same machine to perform certain operations. Right now, anyone can call the self-hosted WCF function directly to perform the operations. I want to prevent this and only allow users of my ASP.NET MVC web app to call the WCF services. What is the efficient way to secure my WCF service without performance impact.
As per Microsoft's article, TransportWithMessageCredential security mode is the best way when compared to Transport security mode and Message Security mode. Is there any samples available online to implement the same? I would like to confirm whether I can follow the steps provided in this link?

The steps in that link use certificates for authentication. This is very secure, but you need to provide each client with an identifying certificate.

Since the verification needs to rely on the X509 certificate, we need to create a certificate first, you can use the MS built-in makecert.exe program to make the test certificate, use the steps: please open Start->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (VS menu, different version, different name) ->Visual Studio Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt, Then execute the following command:
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=QiYouCert" -ss TrustedPeople -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange


Run MMC, the first time you open Windows does not give us the entrance to prepare a direct management certificate, you need to add it yourself, the method of adding is as follows:
In the console menu, select "Certificates" → "Certificates" → Add button Add → Add →→ "My User Account" → close → OK.
In the console menu, add → button →Add/Remove snap-ins → select "Certificates", select "Certificates→ add→ select "Computer Accounts", → close → OK.

To implement username and password authentication, you need to define a username and password authenticator class inherited from UserNamePasswordValidator, CustomUserNameValidator with the following code:
namespace WcfAuthentications
{
    public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
 
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (null == userName || null == password)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
            if (userName != "admin" && password != "wcf.admin") 
            {
                throw new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Password");
            }
 
        }
    }
}

App.config part
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="Service1Binding">
        <security mode="Message">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior" name="WcfAuthentications.Service1">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service1Binding"
        contract="WcfAuthentications.IService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="QiYouCert" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/WcfAuthentications/Service1/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="QiYouCert" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
            customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfAuthentications.CustomUserNameValidator,WcfAuthentications" />
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

In ASP.NET MVC. After referencing the service, enter the following code:
  public ActionResult About()
  {

      var proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

      proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
      proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "wcf.admin";
      string result = proxy.GetData(1);

      ViewBag.Message = result;
     

      return View();
  }

If the password is incorrect, the error will be exploded:
